# Windows Store Template Missing Even After Installing SDK for Windows 8.1

Tags: sdk, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am an absolute beginner to develop Windows Apps for desktop. I have installed windows 8.1, Visual Studiio 2013 and SDK related to it but still unable to get the Windows Store Template to develop apps either by using XAML or JavaScript. Can somebody please help me to solve this issue...Wasted two days already troubleshooting the issue on my own.

Thank you for your time in advance,

Bhargav Krishna.

Comment: Post screenshot of the new project window.

Comment: Hello Friend..thanks for your prompt reply..Jisha Puniyani's answer solved all the issues..thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Store Apps are different than the Windows Apps for the desktop. You need to first figure out what you are trying to develop.

You would use **Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows** for Store apps

or **Visual Studio Express 2013 for Desktop** for Desktop apps.

Comment: Hello Jisha...You are right. I had installed VS2013 for Desktop and searching for Windows store template. Thank you so much for your prompt reply...Issue was resolved. Great work.. :) Thanx again..